# Readonly NumericTextBox - disable the click event that shows the hidden input

Tags: kendo-ui

We are using a Kendo NumericTextBox widget to display a calculated value to the user. We want the value shown to change as the viewmodel changes, but we do not want the user to be able to edit the value.

We have tried: 
 - disabling the widget. This disables user interaction, as required, but it does not allow the value to be updated by the view model.
 - setting the widget as readonly. This allows the value to be updated, and does not allow the user to change the value directly, but the look of the widget changes when the user clicks on it.

We are trying to find a way to have something in between these two, where the value can be changed programmatically, but not by the user. And where there is no visible effect when the user clicks on the widget.

[image]

Is this possible with a Kendo NumericTextBox?

Edit: The issue is that changes to the viewmodel are sent back to the server by serializing the form, and disabled inputs don't get included in the form serialization. This is not an issue with the widget itself, as pointed out by CodingWithSpike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the widget when rendering the page to the user - this will still show updated values when they are re-calculated from other input. Then re-enable the widgets just before serializing the form back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The widget seems to update fine when set on the viewmodel, and the widget is disabled.

[See this example](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/igeD).

```
<input data-role="numerictextbox"
       data-format="c"
       data-min="0"
       data-max="100"
       data-bind="enabled: isEnabled,
                  value: selectedNumber">

<button type="button" data-bind="click: up">Incrament</button>

...

<script>
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        selectedNumber: 0,
        isEnabled: false,
        up: function () { viewModel.set("selectedNumber", viewModel.selectedNumber + 1); }
    });
    kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out. Turns out I was mis-remembering how the widget worked. You are correct, and I now found a work-around based on this.